# gcloud CLI command shows error INVALID_ARGUMENT when listing assets for project ID for some accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I tried to run following command

```
gcloud scc assets list projects/project-id
```

and I got this error,

**ERROR: (gcloud.scc.assets.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.**

I have already updated gcloud SDK to the latest version (350.0.0)

Comment: My guess is that you have an IAM permission problem. 1) Run this command **gcloud info --run-diagnostics**. Any issues reported? 2) Run this command **gcloud scc assets list projects/project-id --verbosity=debug**. 3) Then try this level **gcloud scc assets list projects/project-id --log-http**.

Comment: @JohnHanley when I run " gcloud info --run-diagnostics " command, i didn't get any issues. Both Network diagnostic and Property diagnostic were passed. after I run " gcloud scc assets list projects/project-id --log-http" command.  then i got this error , "ERROR: (gcloud.scc.assets.list) Parent must match either [0-9]+, organization/[0-9]+, projects/.* or folders/.*.

Comment: The error message means that **projects/project-id** is invalid. The regular expression is `projects/.*` and I do not see an issue based upon your example. This is one example where I need to see the actual arguments you are using and the structure of your org. Without details, you will need Google Support. You can report this as a bug here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 0):

**[Listing all assets](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-api-list-assets#listing_all_assets)**

These examples show how to list all assets for an organization:

*# ORGANIZATION_ID=12344321*

```
 $ gcloud scc assets list $ORGANIZATION_ID
```

For more examples, run:

```
  $  gcloud scc assets list --help
```

**[Could you use the following commands:](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/scc/assets/list)**

NAME

`gcloud alpha scc assets list`  - list Cloud Security Command Center assets

List all assets under project (*example-project*)

```
$  gcloud alpha scc assets list projects/example-project
```

OR

List all assets under organization (*123456*)

```
$  gcloud alpha scc assets list 123456
```

**NOTES**

This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice. If this command fails with API permission errors despite specifying the right project, you may be trying to access an API with an invitation-only early access allowlist. These variants are also available:

```
$  gcloud scc assets list
```

```
$  gcloud beta scc assets list
```

**As per from the references you are trying to run a invalid command, if you wanna try with the same cli you have to add the alpha as parameter**